# Rounding off figures

Tags: arithmetic

A solid block has a mass of 23 grams when corrected to the nearest gram.

Find the greatest possible mass of the block .

My answer is 23.4kg and I got wrong and the answer is 23.5kg . I was wondering why 23.5 as 23.5 to nearest gram is 24g. Any one can help me on this ?

Comment: $23.5$ kg is just as close to $24$ g as it is to $23$ g.  You certainly cannot say $23.4$ g since $23.45$ g is higher and yet could _also_ be rounded (to the nearest gram) to $23$ g.  And note that $23.49999$ g would be rounded, to the nearest gram, to $23$ g.

Comment: So in these cases I just take 23.5kg ? @Jared

Comment: @Jared what about least possible mass ?  Is it 22.5g ?